# Difference between Laravel Cashier and Cartalyst Stripe package

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I want to integrate Stripe into my Laravel app, and I'm wondering what is better solution for it: https://github.com/cartalyst/stripe-laravel or https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/billing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only performing "one-off" charges use the `Stripe SDK` directly or `stripe-laravel` by Cartalyst. https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe-laravel/

If you're offering subscriptions, you should use `Laravel Cashier` instead. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing

Comment: Cartalyst Stripe supports subscriptions as well see: https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/2.0#subscriptions

Comment: Why is this the answer there's no direct comparison?